# Does firebase functions keep running after dissiming a view-controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie in iOS development/firebase.
I have two view controller,
the first one does nothing expect performing a segue to the second view-controller
The second the view controller I have two buttons,the firstone is (back) which dismiss a view controller and the second button(up) have the following code
Database.database().child(“posts”).setValue(1)

1- If I have an extremely bad internet connection, and I pressed on up button then immediately pressed on back,
Does the code for uploading data for firebase stop on continue?
2- After pressing up, I immediately go to background and dismiss the app, will it continue setting the data?

Comment: In short yes in both mentioned conditions

Comment: So the function runs in a different class?

Comment: Yes because we are not making an object of Database for each controller its shared

Answer (score 1):

All database operations are handled on another thread that's not related to any UI elements in your app.  As long as your app is running, database operations will continue until complete.

If the app is no longer running, database operations will stop.  If database persistence is not enabled, all of that pending work will never complete.  If database persistence *is* enabled, then the SDK will try again to synchronize the writes that didn't complete previously.